# Manfrotto quick release on Dolica ball head?

Tags: video

I'm considering buying a dolica tripod with ball head, and my question is if the dolica ball head will accept manfrotto quick release plates. I figure it probably won't, so is there any any adapter that will make it work? How do you guys deal with quick relases and different platforms?